# How to do re.findall('\w+', fin.read()) for unicode? python

Tags: python, regex, text-files, counter, n-gram

Is there a way to do the following for textfiles with unicode characters, e.g. chinese/japanese:

```
with io.open(infile, 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
  words = re.findall('\w+', fin.read())
  x = Counter(zip(words,words[1:]))
print x
```

I tried but `x` returns:

```
[]
```

Comment: i guess i could have also done `fin.read().split()`

Comment: Pass [`flags=re.U`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.U).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ashwini Chaudhary commented, you need to specify [`re.U`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.U) or [`re.UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag to make the pattern `\w` dependdent on Unicode character property database.

```
>>> re.findall('\w+', u'單語')
[]
>>> re.findall('\w+', u'單語', flags=re.UNICODE)
[u'\u55ae\u8a9e']
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ashiwini suggested, this worked:

```
words = re.findall('\w+', trgfin.read(), flags=re.U)
x = Counter(zip(words, words[1:])
```